# What are the Vital Things noticed in an Experienced Programmer Resume by a firm?

Tags: self-improvement

Hai Friends,
              Tell me or share with me , i am developer with one year experience, now i want to modify my old fresher resume to an experience resume, so i want to know what are the primary things must be in an experienced resume which is attracted by the firm.

Comment: You are not really an *"Experienced"* programmer after one year. You are a programmer with some experience. It's quite a difference.

Comment: Spelling and grammar: "i am developer" -> " **I** am **a** developer". "primary things must" -> "primary things **that** must". "which is attracted by the firm" -> Which **will be noticed** by **a** firm". "frim" -> "f **ir** m". And that's just the start. I'm not being pedantic here, and I know the standards online are lower. I'm sure you are more careful when writing your resume. When I read a resume I will forgive the occasional mistake, but in general I expect good grammar and spelling.

Comment: "Standards online are lower" - just remember that all the world's not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Frank: Yeah, which is at least partly why spelling/grammar standards online are lower, some leeway is granted as the background isn't known. The comment is about CVs though and is valid regardless of language. If you are writing a CV in English it should contain good spelling and grammar irrespective of your native language. If your CV isn't in English is should still match the standards dictated by the language it is written in.

Comment: @Simon yes: if it's an Afrikaans CV it should be in well-written Afrikaans. I'm just pointing out that Tilsan's writing in English because this is a de facto English forum, while he/she would probably apply in whatever language he/she knows best.

Comment: @Frank shearar: Thanks for ur replay which guided me a lot !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One bit of advice I like (not mine, but I'm too lazy to look for sources) is to **explain** how each of your projects helped your customer/user/employer to improve or "generate value".

Example, you might have an item that reads:

- Implemented Winforms application with .NET 2.0/Infragistics 2.3/SQL Server 2005/Crystal Reports 10.2/C#/Visual Studio 2005.

Try to rephrase to something like:

- Designed, built and delivered a desktop reporting application that helped the Accounting Dept. to reduce invoice payment time from a manual task that used to take 3 days to an automated process based on realtime updated reports that now takes 10 minutes end to end. Implemented as a Windows application built on the Microsoft .NET platform.

Explain what your employer achieved with your work.

The technology tag soup can be left at the end of your resumé just to please recruiters that like to do text search for buzzwords.